# Prettier JSON formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Is there any way to disable prettier for the following below. It keeps changing my below code from

```
User.find({ "username": req.body.Username }
```

to

```
User.find({ username: req.body.Username }
```

It keeps deleting the quotation marks around username and I can't seem to get a way around this. I tried going into settings and un-checking JSON › Format: Enable but no luck. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Prettier offers a way to avoid formatting some parts of code.

As shown in the [documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#javascript), using a `// prettier-ignore` comment can bypass the formatting for the next Abstract Syntax Tree node:

```js
matrix(
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1
)

// prettier-ignore
matrix(
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1
)
```

The first part is prettified meanwhile the next one is left untouched:

```js
matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);

// prettier-ignore
matrix(
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1
)
```